# Confusing about the borrower checker of Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement something similar to `get_or_default`, but the compiler complained borrow check is failed, the simplified code is as following:

```rust
struct A {
    a: Option<String>
}

impl A {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> &String {
        if let Some(a) = self.a.as_ref() {
            return a;
        }
        
        self.a = Some(String::new());
        return self.a.as_ref().unwrap();
    }
}
```

It seems the scope of mutable and immutable reference haven't overlapped, what is the reason of the error? Thanks!

Comment: You are right. This is due to a known limitation of tge current borrow checker. It will likely be fixed in the future. Until then, you need a workaround.

Comment: See https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663

Comment: This is the fourth “confusing about” [question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615) you have written on this site.